# Angular Nested ng-repeats with json call not working

Tags: json, angularjs, nested, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am attempting to make a nested list like this using ng-repeat and a json file:

```
    [] Pizza King North Region
       [] Pizza King 102 
       [] Pizza King 103    
       [] Pizza King 104
   [] Pizza King South Region     
      [] Pizza King 201    
      [] Pizza King 202
   [] Pizza King East Region   
      [] Pizza King 203    
      [] Pizza King 204   
   etc...
```

This is my json object

```
 {
  "groups": [
    {
      "group_id": "Pizza King North Region",
      "systems" : [
        {
          "panel_id": "Pizza King 101"
        },
        {
          "panel_id": "Pizza King 102"
        },
        {
          "panel_id": "Pizza King 103"
        },
        {
          "panel_id": "Pizza King 104"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "group_id": "Pizza King South Region",
      "systems" : [
        {
          "panel_id": "Pizza King 101"
        },
        {
          "panel_id": "Pizza King 102"
        },
        {
          "panel_id": "Pizza King 103"
        },
        {
          "panel_id": "Pizza King 104"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "group_id": "Pizza King East Region",
      "systems" : [
        {
          "panel_id": "Pizza King 101"
        },
        {
          "panel_id": "Pizza King 102"
        },
        {
          "panel_id": "Pizza King 103"
        },
        {
          "panel_id": "Pizza King 104"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "group_id": "Pizza King West Region",
      "systems" : [
        {
          "panel_id": "Pizza King 101"
        },
        {
          "panel_id": "Pizza King 102"
        },
        {
          "panel_id": "Pizza King 103"
        },
        {
          "panel_id": "Pizza King 104"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "systems": [
    {
      "panel_id": "Pizza King 101"
    },
    {
      "panel_id": "Pizza King 102"
    },
    {
      "panel_id": "Pizza King 103"
    },
    {
      "panel_id": "Pizza King 104"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is how I'm bringing it into my app in the controller:

```
    App.controller('AddUserMultiCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$http', '$modal', function ($rootScope, $scope, $http, $modal) {

  var addUserMulti = this; // controllerAs
  console.clear();

  $http.get('app/users/data-temp/systems.json')
    .success(function(response) {
      addUserMulti.groups = response.groups;
      addUserMulti.systems = response.systems;
    })
    .error(function (data) {
      console.log("Error retrieving user data.");
    });
```

This is my html:

```
<ul class="nav">

  <li ng-repeat="group in addUserMulti.groups">
    <label class="checkbox checkbox-inline c-checkbox"> <input id="inlineCheckbox1" type="checkbox"
      value="option1"/><span class="fa fa-check"></span><strong>{{group.group_id}}</strong></label><i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-2x pull-right"></i>
  </li>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li ng-repeat="system in group.systems">
      <label class="checkbox checkbox-inline c-checkbox"> <input id="{{ system.panel_id }}" type="checkbox"
        value="option1">{{ system.panel_id }} </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

This is the result: My Groups come in but no nested systems

I get a list of parent items, but no children.

I would sure appreciate some direction on  this as all code examples that I have tried to follow aren't working so far!

Comment: Your ng-repeat are NOT nested. They should be. Put the second <ul> *inside* the group <li>

Comment: ty JB Nizet! I hate it when the obvious is missed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ul class="nav">

  <li ng-repeat="group in addUserMulti.groups">
    <label class="checkbox checkbox-inline c-checkbox"> <input id="inlineCheckbox1" type="checkbox"
      value="option1"/><span class="fa fa-check"></span><strong>{{group.group_id}}</strong></label><i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-2x pull-right"></i>

    <ul class="nav">
      <li ng-repeat="system in group.systems">
        <label class="checkbox checkbox-inline c-checkbox"> <input id="{{ system.panel_id }}" type="checkbox" ="option1">{{ system.panel_id }} </label>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </li>      
</ul>
```

This way, group is properly nested and so `group.systems` exists.

Answer (score 1):

Systems is an array inside groups so if you don't iterate systems inside groups you won't see any children.

You have to put your `system in group.systems` block **inside** your `group in addUserMulti.groups` block.